# are javascript variable string by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im creating a ZoomIn icon for my cars.

```
<img src="~/Content/center-icon.png" id="center-@car.Car_ID" data-x=@car.X data-y=@car.Y />
                                                                     ^^         ^^ float
```

I get the data from the clicked event

```
var $carCenterId = $('#' + event.target.id)

var x = $carCenterId.data("x");
var y = $carCenterId.data("y");

carZoomCenter(x, y);
```

But my function wasnt working because treat x and y as strings.

```
function carZoomCenter(x, y) {

    console.log(typeof x);   // return string

    x = Number(x);
    y = Number(y);

    console.log(typeof x);  // return number

    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new
          ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([x, y], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        name: 'Null Island ',              ^^^^ fail if are string
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });
}
```

After adding `Number()`, function is working ok. I know javascript doesnt declare types. but Im wondering if that is the way to do it or if I missing something.

Comment: No, javascript *variables* in general don't default to a string type (as you know, variables don't have types). The results of `.data()` calls might be string values by default.

Comment: @Bergi So I should use `var x = Number($carCenterId.data("x"));` instead?

Comment: Btw they **have** types. `typeof x` return string or number.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Depends on whether you will want to expect your `carZoomCenter(x, y)` function to always take numbers or to allow strings as well.

Comment: `typeof` does return the type of the value, not of the variable. Variables can hold anything.

Comment: How is the "rendered" HTML? I think that the render engine is rendering that as string. You can check an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/n0y0cbp7/

Comment: @WilliamMartins Yes, in my case say is a string :$ `121.10205000 string` .... even if I change the C# variable for the literal `data-x=121.10205000` still said is a string

Comment: If you are certain that `x` and `y` hold a number written in form of string then just use `x = +x; // outputs the number...`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, how is this being render? I mean, what "framework" (or something like that) are you using? Try to check the docks to see if they have some kind of way to "force" the type

Comment: I dont know what you mean, Im using framework 4.5. change your sentence for `console.log( $carCenterId.data('x') + ' ' + typeof ($carCenterId.data('x')) );` and return string as I show you.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, sorry, I wasn't clear in my previous question. What is the **name** of the framework/lib that you are using? Because I've never seen this "`data-x=@car.X`" syntax before.

Comment: @WilliamMartins `data`part I  think that is [HTML 5](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)   `@car.x` is Razor engine from C#

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, as I can see, Razor engine is the problem, since it is always rendering your data-attributes as string. You may check how Razor engine is rendering that for you. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0y0cbp7/1/. Can you try wrapping `data-x=@car.X` like that: `data-x="@car.X"` (notice the quotes)?

Comment: @WilliamMartins Sorry I miss this comment. Check `Amir Popovich` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8b9b7gt/). Depending on the content length javascript convert it to number or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the value will be a string because under the hood, the `data()` jQuery method is calling the JavaScript `getAttribute()` method on the DOM element. And attribute values on HTML elements are string values and are returned as strings.

You can also look into the `parseFloat()` and `parseInt()` methods of JavaScript to force the conversion to a number.

```
var x = parseFloat($carCenterId.data("x"));
var y = parseFloat($carCenterId.data("y"));
```

JavaScript does not default things to string. It does support types, but it also doesn't enforce them unless you want it to. JavaScript will try to coerce types by inferring what you want. Like this:

```
var x = "2";
var y = x * 2;
console.log(y === 4); //logs true
```

JavaScript will coerce the string into a number and y will be the result. Similarly:

```
var i = 2;
var k = i + "";
console.log(typeof k === "string"); //logs true
```

Types can seem to be very fluid, and JavaScript can coerce them in unexpected ways if you aren't careful. When you have logic that requires variables to be specific types, it's best to force them into the types you need.

Comment: When used to retrieve `data-` attributes set in the html, the `.data()` method attempts to "convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)", so it certainly doesn't always return a string. (Some things that look like numbers are left as strings, but plain integer values will be converted to numbers.)

Comment: @nnnnnn what about float? Maybe that is why my 120.124566 is string but fiddle 5 show number

Comment: I have had mixed results with JavaScript typing (including jQuery). I always include logic to force types when they matter. Just about the time I think I have a handle on it, turns out I don't.

Comment: I never use `.data()` to retrieve `data-` attributes, because I don't want jQuery deciding for me what type it is going to return. So I would always use `.attr()` for that and do my own conversion. (I only use `.data()` to retrieve values that I *set* with `.data()`, which are not stored as html attributes.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to do that. But didnt know how. So I solve it creating the html attributes in the `@foreach` loop   ... if you know how create the .data from a c# model let me know.

Answer (score 4):

No, javascript vars are undefined by default and their type can be changed on the fly.

```js
var x; 
console.log(x === undefined);
x = "6";
console.log(typeof x === 'string');
x = 7;
console.log(typeof x === 'number');
```

The reason you are getting strings is because you have large floats that jquery's data method doesn't succeed converting them into numbers.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8b9b7gt/) to understand.
You might want to fix this by limiting the number of digits after the floating point.

Comment: so why sql fiddle by William show type is integer and mine show string?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I didn't understand your question. What is sql fiddle by William? You need to understand, A html attribute = string. That's the reason you get a string. Simply convert it into a Number if you know that's what you are expecting.

Comment: *"The reason you are getting strings is because an attribute is html and it's value is a string."* - Except that the OP is using jQuery's `.data()` method, which, when retrieving html `data-` attributes, *does* convert strings to numbers - but it only does this for some formats.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right... `120` is a number but `120.123456` is a string.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I've updated my answer and added a fiddle. Check it out.

Comment: @AmirPopovich that is even weirder. Thanks for your help. I go with jwatts answer because give the fix .... force it if you dont know what is.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript variables by default are set to undefined:

```
var jvar;
console.log(jvar); // return undefined
```

In your instance, you're using JQuery to get an element and extract a data attribute from that element. By default, attributes from JQuery elements are string or an object. See [JQuery docs about the data method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for more details.